# How to avoid "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" while running "REPLACE INTO" query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I try to copy data from source table to target table which these tables have the same structure except foerign key constraints that only have in target table. The query I use is this follow:

`REPLACE INTO mydb.src_table SELECT * FROM mydb.target_table`

and then I got this error

`IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`target_table`, CONSTRAINT` fk_id `FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES` project `(`project_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)')`

Can anyone have any solution about this?

I also use 'INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...' and got the same error.

I need to run any query (REPLACE or INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY) in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to disable the foreign key check- make the changes then re-enable foreign key check.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; -- to disable
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- to re-enable
```

Comment: in laravel i did something like this ```DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'); then my migration code and then DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');``` works like a charm thanks.